# Singular subject + every/all

Tags: sentence-construction

> 1. Game of Thrones has seven kingdoms and each one of them represents *every* seven continents of the world.
> 2. Game of Thrones has seven kingdoms and each one of them represents *all* the seven continents of the world.

Which one is correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that *each* is the word you want to use here.  *Each of them represents..." means that each of them **individually** does that, and it sounds very strange to say that every one of the Game of Thrones kingdom represents seven different kingdoms.

Comment: Your sentences don't make any sense in terms of logic. Therefore it is impossible to say whether the English correctly represents your meaning. Don't assume that everyone has watched Game of Thrones!  You need to explain the difference between GoT kingdoms and "kingdoms of the world."  Also please explain in more detail what situation these sentences are describing.

Comment: Changed the second ‘kingdoms’ to ‘continents’. Sorry I was in rush.

Answer (score 1):

#### Both constructions are valid.*

*Rather, they can be. See first example.

You *could* use "every" or "all" in this context, but your first example has a grammatical error. The second example is grammatical, but neither of these make much sense even if this is corrected.

You can say

> Game of Thrones has seven kingdoms and each of them represents every **one of the** seven kingdom**s** of the world.

You can also say

> Game of Thrones has seven kingdoms and each of them represents all the seven kingdoms of the world.

Both of these sentences mean the same thing and are grammatical with the corrections in **bold**. However, this would imply that for any *one* given kingdom in Game of Thrones, that kingdom somehow represents "all seven" kingdoms of the world. I don't know what you mean by the "seven kingdoms of the world" in the first place, but it seems odd for one kingdom in the books/show to represent all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Some rules I know:

- every [singular].
- all of the [plural].

For instance:

- Every *person* I know likes to dance
- All of the *people* I know like to dance

or

- Every animal has to breath
- All of the animal**s** have to breath

Like the other answer pointed out, there's a grammatical error in the first. It could be changed to where "every" is used correctly.